# Thread does not execute Runnable posted by Handler in Service onStartCommand

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I have a Service that creates a `HandlerThread`, and a `Handler` for it during the `onCreate` method.
The handler is used to `post` a `Runnable` in the same method, which gets executed normally on that background thread as expected.
On the service's `onStartCommand` the handler is used to post a different `Runnable`, and exits normally.

The problem is that the `Runnable` posted in the `onStartCommand` method is never called.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("BackgroundThread");
  thread.start();
  Looper looper = thread.getLooper();
  handler = new Handler(looper);
  handler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          methodThatGetsExecuted();
      }
  });
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      methodThatNeverGetsCalled();
    }
  });
  return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```